# How to send end-to-end encryption code securely

Tags: security, https

I need to make a secure chat server with end-to-end encryption support, theoretically I know how it works but I don't know how to send an encryption key over ssl.

Comment: This is way too broad. To answer this would require writing up a huge tutorial. Have you tried doing this already? What specific problem did you run into?

Comment: I have a working  chat server, I just don't know how to share an ecryption key securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a proven key exchange algorithm such as [Diffie–Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

Otherwise you can rely on asymmetric keys to then exchange a new/temporary symmetric key. For example, each side sends half of a symmetric key which is encrypted with each-others' public key.